# Периоды времени в celery add_periodic_task()

Tags: python, django, celery

У меня в проекте есть код для запуска задач по времени:

```
@app.on_after_finalize.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(60.0 * 10, update_info.signature(), name='update_info')
```

Было бы тут просто `60`, то задача бы запускалась каждую минуту. Но что значит `60 * 10`? Что задача будет запускаться раз в 10 минут или же это для часового пояса, как, например в:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=11 - 3, minute=40))
```

?

Только начинаю работать с `celery` и везде, где есть какая-то информация про время обычно либо про `crontab`, либо простые варианты с числами по типу `60`, но ничего про варианты с "`*`", как у меня.

Подскажите, какой промежуток времени имеется в виду под "`60 * 10`" и зачем обозначать именно так?

Answer (score 0):

Это означает как раз выполнение раз в 10 минут, а указывается в коде таким образом, чтобы программисту, читающему код, было интуитивно понятно о каком отрезке времени идёт речь.
Это распространённая практика, много где можно встретить, например, 24 * 60 * 60 вместо 86400 при указании длительности суток в секундах.